# How do I subscribe to Facebook messenger events using ng2-facebook-sdk?

Tags: angular, facebook-messenger

How do I subscribe to Facebook messenger events using ng2-facebook-sdk?

I'm using the Facebook ***[Send to Messenger](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/plugin-reference/send-to-messenger)*** plugin with this template:

```
<div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
  messenger_app_id="APP_ID" 
  page_id="PAGE_ID" 
  data-ref="PASS_THROUGH_PARAM" 
  color="blue" 
  size="standard">
</div>
```

The code without the library is as follows:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('send_to_messenger', function(e) {
   // callback for events triggered by the plugin

 });
```

The [ng2-faceook-sdk](https://github.com/zyramedia/ng2-facebook-sdk) is a wrapper for the official Facebook JavaScript SDK.

Comment: Did you found a solution ?